# Smooth scroll not making it to anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I am currently working on a one-page website using smooth scroll. Currently, I can scroll to each individual section just fine from the top of the page, but when I am in the "team" section and try to go to the "about" section the page does not scroll all the way to the anchor. And, when I try to scroll from the "about" section to the "team" section, the page just scrolls to the top. I am also using bootstrap v4. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a link to the page I got my smoothscroll javascript from: [Quick Guide: Adding Smooth Scrolling to Your Webpages](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/)

This is the html tag: `<html id="home">`

Here is part of my index file:

```
<div class="d-flex toggled" id="wrapper">
      <?php require 'sidebar.php'; ?>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar-inverse">
          <button class="btn btn-lg menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
              <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
      </nav>
        <?php require 'carousel.php'; ?>
        <?php require 'team.php'; ?>
      <hr style="clear: both;"/>
        <?php require 'about.php'; ?>
      <hr style="clear: both;"/>
  </div>
```

Here is the top of my "team" section, which currently works when scrolling from the top, but not from the about section:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-50 page-section">
  <a class="section-link" name="team"></a>
<div class="row section-title">
```

Here is the top of my "about" section, which only works correctly when scrolled to from the top of the page.

```
<div class="container-fluid h-50 page-section">
  <a class="section-link" name="about"></a>
<div class="row section-title">
```

Here is some of my CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.page-section {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 5rem;

}

.section-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Hopefully, this is enough information for you to see where my problem is.
Thanks in advance!